# How to make places in Google Maps to be objects like maps.google.com with Google Maps API in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When using maps.google.com, places like parks,bus stations, restaurants are objects and we can mouse-hover to display the place's detail. See image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfRDo.png

But we can't do that with only Google Maps API. See image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SU9uC.png

Thank in advance !

ps1 : The default Maps application in Andoird also has this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to use an `Overlay`, or override `onTouchEvent()` in a custom subclass of `MapView`, to find out when the user taps the screen. You are welcome to use a `Projection` to determine the latitude and longitude of where the user tapped. You are welcome to pass that data to some Web service that can tell you what is at that location. And you are welcome to display those results in some form (e.g., `Toast`).

However, none of that is built into the Google Maps SDK add-on for Android.

Comment: Thanks but I think it is impossible to add them manually to all places.

Comment: The default Maps application in Andoird also has this feature. Do you have any idea about how they do ? Image : http://i.imgur.com/YJpX8.png

Comment: let me think: probably exaclty like was explained above. Just that they probably retrive the location info WITH the map data. You know, they're the makers of it.

Comment: The Google Maps application is not using the Google Maps SDK add-on at present.